# <span> jQuery .click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I created a delete "button" in a span, but for some reason I can't get the .click() to fire.  Any ideas?  I'm new to jQuery and am thinking that it's something obvious.  I tested in Chrome and Safari with no luck.

CSS:

```
.delete_button {
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #AAA;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<span class="delete_button" id="delete_<? echo $some_id; ?>">X</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete_button').click(function() {
            var transaction_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('delete_','');
            alert("Delete transaction #" + transaction_id);
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you adding them dynamically?

Comment: Not sure why everyone assumes he's adding the button dynamically... it has PHP in it, so it may not be...

Comment: @HamzaKubba Yeah you can see 2 answer already there. Probably the frequency of the similar question every day.. :) If not the answer should work without any issues.

Comment: @HamzaKubba because the code is correct and using dynamic id, most likley delete_1,2,3,4

Comment: @CharlesHarrison: Add an alert before this line: `$('.delete_button').click(function() {`
See if that code is running at all.

Comment: The ID is written with PHP... so it may very well be there on page load. Javascript is not the only way to do thing dynamically on a page. He *may* be doing it dynamically, but people shouldn't assume so.

Comment: @HamzaKubba have a look at it.. That was the issue only i guess. :)

Comment: @HamzaKubba If it wouldn't have been correct the OP will write it in the comment of the answer.

Comment: Yup, the assumption turned out to be correct.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your span is added dynamically so it is not present at the time DOM ready or page load.

So you have to use [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

like this

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_button',function(){
    // code here
});
```

or

```
$('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').on('click','.delete_button',function(){
   // code here
});
```

your code becomes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete_button', function () {
        var transaction_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('delete_', '');
        alert("Delete transaction #" + transaction_id);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Note: using $(document).on('click','.delete_button',function(event){ will also allow you to use event.preventDefault()

Comment: > $('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').on('click','.delete_button',delegate);

This worked well for me. I then simplified it to an alternate jQuery syntax, just for the sake of my preferred syntax:
$('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').find('.delete_button').click(delegate)

Comment: Hey it's really helped me!

Comment: This is the first time I fully understand why dynamically added element dont works with `$('#foo').on('click', ...)`. Now I get it :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 13):

It seems like the span is dynamically created, you need to use event delegation. Bind it to the closest static parent or document

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_button',function(){
   /*Your code*/
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simpler solution for old webkit: set cursor to pointer via CSS for the span.
Tested and working on a music web app.

Comment: What relevance does this have? The question is about **clicking**, not about the cursor appearance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately I don't think this is what the question was asking for - the issue was with events being fired or not being fired, not the styling of the cursor.